# Проблема с поиском числа инверсий в массиве через алгоритм MergeSort

Tags: c#

Есть рабочий алгоритм MergeSort. Нужно модифицировать его так, чтобы он по совместительству находил и число инверсий в массиве.

Инверсией считается пара чисел массива, если выполняется условие A[left] > A[right]. И так же все оставшиеся элементы левой части тоже будут больше, т.к. левая и правая часть отсортированы. Поэтому количество инверсий нужно увеличить на количество оставшихся элементов + 1 (текущий элемент).

Проблема заключается в том, что, например, в таком наборе чисел «145, 179, 232, 307, 588, 792, 22, 233, 279, 336, 863, 866» кол-во инверсий равно числу 14, а на выводе 15. Хотя при другом наборе, например, «1, 5, 8, 3, 7, 10» выводит правильное число, это 3.

Вот моя наработка:

```
public static void MargeSort(int[] array, int l, int r)
{
    if ((r - l) < 2)
        return;
    MargeSort(array, l, (l + r) / 2);
    MargeSort(array, (l + r) / 2, r);
    Marge(array, l, r);
}

private static int inversionsCount = 0;
public static void Marge(int[] array, int l, int r)
{
    int middle = (l + r) / 2;
    int left = l;
    int right = middle;
    int index = 0;

    int[] buff = new int[r - l];

    while ((left < middle) && (right < r))
    {
        if (array[left] > array[right])
        {
            buff[index++] = array[left++];
            // здесь идет подсчет кол-ва инверсий
            inversionsCount += middle - left;
        }
        else buff[index++] = array[right++];
    }

    while (left < middle)
        buff[index++] = array[left++];
    while (right < r)
        buff[index++] = array[right++];

    index = 0;
    while (index < buff.Length)
        array[l + index] = buff[index++];
}
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался с проблемой. Прикол в том, что нужно было просто исключить из числа инверсий все повторения входных чисел.

То есть. Например, при наборе чисел «7, 4, 1, 9, 1», результатом должно быть 6. А по старому алгоритму считало 7.

Достичь правильного результата в данном примере можно двумя путями:

1)  Добавить такое условие:

`if(array[left] != array[right])
     inversionsCount += middle - left;`

Но с другими примерами результат будет неверным!
Поэтому лучше воспользоваться пунктом 2.

2) Вот оно, универсальное решение.

```
while ((left < middle) && (right < r))
    {
        if (array[left] <= array[right])
            buff[index++] = array[left++];
        else
        {
            inversionsCount += middle - left;
            buff[index++] = array[right++];
        }
    }
```

В первом if нужно поставить `<=` вместо `<`.